# Generate Java code from XSD and WSDL

Tags: java

I have a folder containing multiple xsd, and wsdl files. How do I use all of them to generate Java classes? I know how to generate java code from a single wsdl file, but I have multiple xsds and wsdls

Comment: Use `wsimport` to generate Java code from WSDLs. `xjc` can be used to generate Java code for standalone XSDs (it's unnecessary to use if those XSDs are included by the WSDL(s)).

Comment: Do you use Netbeans or Eclipse?

Comment: I use eclipse. Is there an option to do it in eclipse?

Comment: you can follow this tutorial: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Generating_a_client_from_WSDL.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven then this will work for you. You probably won't need the bindingDirectory or bindingFiles argument but just in case there is an example.

```
             <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                        <executions>
                                <execution>
                                        <id>submitOrderRequest</id>
                                        <goals>
                                                <goal>xjc</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                        <configuration>
                                                <extension>true</extension>
                                                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd/</schemaDirectory>
                                                <schemaFiles>submitOrderRequest.xsd</schemaFiles>
                                                <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xjb</bindingDirectory>
                                                <bindingFiles>submitOrderRequest.xjb</bindingFiles>
                                                <removeOldOutput>false</removeOldOutput>
                                                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                                        </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>

                    </plugin>
```